# Switch on Nullable Boolean : case goes to null when value is true

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I realize the proper way to handle nullable types is to use the HasValue property. But I would like to know why the following switch statement breaks on the null case instead of default. Using VS2015 C#4.0. Another computer that is using VS2010 C#4.0 does not have this same problem.

```
 private void Testing()
    {
        bool? boolValue = true;

        switch (boolValue)
        {
            case null: 
                break; //even though value is true, code runs here

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

**Edit**: Behavior is observed with any `Nullable` if only `case Null` and `default` is specified.

Comment: I don't get this behavior on VS2013

Comment: I'd guess either your symbols are out of date and it's not running what you think it's running, or maybe the compiler is doing some weird optimization thing and combing the two equal blocks.  Maybe add some actual code in there and see what it does..

Comment: I don't get that behavior in 2010.

Comment: Are you looking at what your debugger tells you, or do you also see this with actual different code in the two cases?

Comment: Have you checked out the IL? (With ildasm?)

Comment: Working fine in VS2015!!!

Comment: If I add a case for value equals true, then it breaks for that case. But without that case, like shown above, it should break on default instead of null.

Comment: Yup got that! Kinda strange though.

Comment: I just duplicated this with visual studio community 2015. It breaks at the first case statement.

Comment: i consider it as bug, in my compiler i get this weird problem too. And no matter bool value is false true or null

Comment: m.kazem, which versions do you have ?

Comment: I have tested this in VS2010, VS2013, and VS2015. Only VS2015 has this issue. The problem seems to be a bug in VS2015. I added some Console.WriteLine to test this. The IL produces by VS2013 contains an if statement. The IL produced by VS2015 does not.

Comment: @MikeG tested on VS 2015. Ive just tested. the bug is for all nullable types like `int?` `enum?`

Comment: @YacoubMassad can you share the IL code generated in VS2015 and any earlier version of VS?

Comment: interesting. this obvious bug was hidden till now!

Comment: Interesting finding. Also wondering who flagged this question lol..

Answer (score 13):

This is going to be a very short answer: You just hit [Roslyn bug #4701](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/4701), reported two weeks ago.

The milestone is set to 1.1, so right now you'll have to workaround this with a separate `if` clause, while waiting for the next compiler update.

Answer (score 5):

This is not an answer, I am just sharing IL code generated by VS2013 and VS2015.

Original C# code:

```
public void Testing()
{
    bool? boolValue = true;

    switch (boolValue)
    {

        case null:

            Console.WriteLine("null");

            break; 

        default:
            Console.WriteLine("default");

            break;
    }
}
```

VS2013 IL (decompiled):

```
public void Testing()
{
    bool? boolValue = new bool?(true);
    bool valueOrDefault = boolValue.GetValueOrDefault();
    if (boolValue.HasValue)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("default");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("null");
    }
}
```

VS2015 IL (decompiled):

```
public void Testing()
{
    bool? flag = new bool?(true);
    bool? flag2 = flag;
    bool? flag3 = flag2;
    if (flag3.HasValue)
    {
        bool valueOrDefault = flag3.GetValueOrDefault();
    }
    Console.WriteLine("null");
}
```

Comment: for me there is only one variable `nullable2`. not flag1,2,3. but it seems the default part does not compile at all. the problem is for all nullable types

Comment: Maybe it depends also on the decompiler. I am using ILSpy

Comment: I have version 14.0.23107.0 D14REL, what version do you have @vendettamit?