# Nullable type in switch Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015

I have this program:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        long? variable = 10;

        switch (variable)
        {
            case 10:
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Hit!");
                return;
            }
            default:
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No hit!");
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

When I compile and run it in Visual Studio 2013, I get the result "Hit!" which is what I expect.
When I compile and run it in Visual Studio 2015, I get the result "No hit!" which is NOT what I expect.  To make this work in Visual Studio 2015, I have to change the switch-statement to `switch(variable.Value)`.

Is this a change in functionality in the new C#-compiler, or is this a bug?

Comment: This question (although about booleans) seems to be similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32407191/switch-on-nullable-boolean-case-goes-to-null-when-value-is-true

Comment: Is this really the same? In the Roslyn-issue it says: "Fix codegen for integral switches with only null and default cases".
My case does not have a null case.