# Nullable Long switch statement not producing expected output in VS2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, switch-statement, nullable

I'm seeing some strange behavior when using a nullable long switch statement in VS2015 Update 1 that I'm not seeing in other Visual Studio releases where it runs as expected.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        NullableTest(-1);
        NullableTest(0);
        NullableTest(1);
        NullableTest(2);
        NullableTest(null);
    }

    public static void NullableTest(long? input)
    {
        string switch1;
        switch (input)
        {
            case 0:
                switch1 = "0";
                break;
            case 1:
                switch1 = "1";
                break;
            default:
                switch1 = "d";
                break;
        }

        string switch2;
        switch (input)
        {
            case -1:
                switch2 = "-1";
                break;
            case 0:
                switch2 = "0";
                break;
            case 1:
                switch2 = "1";
                break;
            default:
                switch2 = "d";
                break;
        }

        string ifElse;
        if (input == 0)
        {
            ifElse = "0";
        }
        else if (input == 1)
        {
            ifElse = "1";
        }
        else
        {
            ifElse = "d";
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Input = {0}, Switch 1 output = {1}, Switch 2 output = {2},  If Else = {3}", input, switch1, switch2,  ifElse);
    }
```

This sample code produces the following output (Aligned for readability):

```
Input = -1, Switch 1 output = d, Switch 2 output = d,  If Else = d
Input = 0,  Switch 1 output = 0, Switch 2 output = d,  If Else = 0
Input = 1,  Switch 1 output = d, Switch 2 output = d,  If Else = 1
Input = 2,  Switch 1 output = d, Switch 2 output = d,  If Else = d
Input = ,   Switch 1 output = d, Switch 2 output = d,  If Else = d
```

I'm only observing this behavior with Nullable types. Non-nullable types work as expected.

Note that this is ***not*** the same behavior that's in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32407191/switch-on-nullable-boolean-case-goes-to-null-when-value-is-true), and is not caused by [this](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/4701) compiler bug that's been fixed in VS2015 Update 1. I've verified that both of those examples run correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this is caused by [this bug](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/7625), and was fixed with [this pull request](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/pull/7627).

I've tried a recent build of Roslyn and the sample code in the question works as expected now.

[Here](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs#d-build-tools) is the updated version of MSBuild Tools 2015 that has corrected the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug. I believe it must be a left over of the same [bug](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/4701). You better replace your code with an `If` to avoid any unexpected behavior.